# wget on behalf of a web user

Tags: javascript, ip, client-side, wget

I'm imagining a web interface that uses wget to retrieve a URL that the web user specifies. The interaction looks like this:

1. The user enters a URL into a web form and submits it to the server.
2. The server retrieves the page with wget and stores it at `/path/to/index.html`.
3. The server redirects the user to `example.com/path/to/index.html`, which serves the page that was just downloaded.

The problem is that I'm worried sites may start throttling the server's IP address if it sends too many requests.

Is it possible to run wget in such a way that it redirects the output to the user's IP address, which the web interface would then redirect to the server? I'm aware that this could lead to a heinously ugly hack, but I'm curious if it's technically feasible.

Comment: Not possible, and for good reason.  If it were possible, gigantic distributed denial of service attacks would be possible with just wget.

Comment: Can't you just do this with an frame/iframe?

Comment: @Wug I can hit any domain `<iframe src="http://www.example.com" />` or `<img src="http://www.example.com" />`

Comment: @Joe, Same origin policy...Means a no go unless CORs is involved.

Comment: @epascarello: the point is, you can't use wget to request a web resource be sent to an arbitrary ip address.  iframes are client-side.  The question addresses a server-side solution.

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A//stackoverflow.com/questions/17154316/wget-on-behalf-of-a-web-user%22%20and%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xpath%3D%27//div%5B@class%3D%22post-text%22%5D%27 works for many sites

Comment: @dandavis: embedding a developer tool in a website is kind of the equivalent of writing an executable that modifies its own state by attaching a debugger to itself.  Sure, it works, but is it the right/simple way to set variables?

Comment: you don't embed any tool, you use it make a jsonp url to fetch 3-rd party domains via YQL so you don't have to run your own proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is that it's probably *possible*, but enormously impractical for the following reasons:

1. Server would need to spoof TCP packets, which it shouldn't be able to.
2. All hops between server and third party would have to accept spoofed traffic, which they shouldn't.
3. Client routers/firewalls would have to accept unsolicited TCP responses, which they won't.
4. Establishing the TCP connection like that would require forwarding all sorts of hairy data from the client to the server, which is a highly platform and network dependent process.
5. In order to authenticate to the third party, you'd have to send your credentials through the process, which is an awful idea.
6. Accepting unsolicited requests in this manner would make you extremely vulnerable to denial of service attacks (Someone generates 10 million requests on your behalf for a 40 megabyte file).